# ReWriteEngine doing opposite of what is wanted

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to create a `ReWriteEngine` rule(s) for a site I maintain. The site has two domain variations `.co.uk`and `.com`. What I'm looking to do is have `.com` rewrite to `.co.uk` but also always make sure the `www.` part is at the beginning. I'm getting reverse and unpredicted behaviour though. See this table for the desired rewrite and what I'm actually getting. The ReWriteCond and ReWriteRule were based on another Stackoverflow questions regarding a similar problem.

```
|    URL ENTERED    |   URL REWRITTEN   |  DESIRED REWRITE  | SUCCESS |
|-------------------|-------------------|-------------------|---------|
| www.example.com   | example.co.uk     | www.example.co.uk | No      |
| example.com       | www.example.co.uk | www.example.co.uk | Yes     |
| example.co.uk     | example.co.uk     | www.example.co.uk | No      |
| www.example.co.uk | www.example.co.uk | www.example.co.uk | Yes     |
```

ReWrite Rule & Condition

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example\.com  [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)  http://www.example.co.uk/$1     [R=301,L,NC]
```

Comment: @martin Thanks for catching that! I hadn't even noticed. It's also apparently using the old address as I've now switched to a .design TLD. That's a whole other saga though as the ReWrites for that have been broken by a tech support member at my hosting company trying to be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may be seeing a cached redirect if you are being redirected to `example.co.uk` (no `www`) since your current directive does not do this. However, if you want to redirect non-www and `www.example.com` then you will need two conditions:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.com [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.example.co.uk/$1 [R=301,L]
```

So, if you access via `www.example.com` *or* the hostname does *not* start `www.` then redirect. (`example.com` is caught by the 2nd condition.)

Removed the `NC` flag from the `RewriteRule` since it is superfluous here (`.*` matches everything, regardless of case.)

Clear your browser cache before testing. Change `R=302` to `R=301` only when you are sure it's working OK.

Comment: It wasn't a caching issue as clearing the caches had no change but your rules fixed it - thanks!

Comment: Well, if the first example wasn't a caching issue then "something else" was causing it - it wasn't the directives you posted.

Comment: It could have been some "security" rewrites that came bundled with the CMS, although they all seem to only rewrite after the tld. It also could have been the host; I had some problems on another site hosted with them where one of their low level tech support guys tried to be helpful by adding rewrite rules after an separate but related issue, but they messed things up.